# Combinatoric Summation

Tags: combinatorics, summation

How do i evaluete : $\sum_{j=0}^{n}\left \{ \binom{n}{j}\; \sum_{i=0}^{j}\binom{j}{i}8^{i} \right \}$. I know $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}=2^{n}$ But how about the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [binomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem):
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{j}\binom{j}{i}8^{i} =
\sum_{i=0}^{j}\binom{j}{i} 1^{j-i}8^{i} =
 (1 + 8)^j = 9^j
$$
Now substitute that in your expression and apply the binomial formula
again ...

Comment: Thank you so much, Its Clear now!